# Reading 4-20ma signal on arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, adc, analogreadresolution

I want to read a 4-20 mA analog signal from a 24V flowmeter. I've read the simplest way is to convert it into 1-5V signal using a 250 ohm resistor. The thing is I want my reading to be precise so my question is; is there any resolution loss when converting it to 1-5V?

I've also looked up on current to voltage converting boards similar to this one: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14544

but I don't think they can detect 4mA signal.

I am a beginner in this so need some guidance here.

Comment: "resolution loss" compared to what?

Comment: compared to current. basically if it has enough sensitivity (to differentiate between 5mV and 15mV). 1023 (10 bit) divisions are spaced out in 4-20mA as compared to 1-5V.

Comment: 10-bit divisions are only spaced between 4 and 20mA if you can somehow subtract 4mA from everything and then arrange it to work from 0-16mA. Subtracting current is hard.

Answer (score 2):

Using a resistor is the "Normal" way, yes. 250Ω will give you 1-5V, yes, which means that you get 4/5 of the actual resolution of the ADC at your disposal.

That means instead of 0-1023 you're actually reading 204-1023, or 819 possible values. Spread over 16ma (or 4V, which are the same thing) that gives you about 20µA resolution.

If you really really care about that extra 1/5 of the resolution you can instead use a 300Ω resistor to give you 1.2 to 6V, then pass that through a subtracting amplifier (see [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/18265/4245)) and subtract 1.1V from it (you need to create that 1.1V, of course).  That will give you 0.1 to 4.9V, which then covers more of the ADC's available range (20-1002, or about 16µA resolution).

Is it worth it? Probably not. Any increase in resolution will likely be swamped by the inaccuracy of the resistor and potential drift though self heating.

Comment: self-heating and resistor in-accuracy will also prevail with a 250 ohm resistor. how is that different?

Comment: @SumitMann it's not. My point is that you will be getting a tiny bit more accuracy or of a system that is inherently inaccurate.

Comment: if this is an inaccurate way, can you suggest me another way to read that analog sensor? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/8/823.html

Comment: How accurate is the flow meter?  No matter how precise or accurate you make the current to voltage conversion, or how well you utilize the Arduino native A/D resolution, you can't do any better than the flow meter's accuracy/precision?  If the flow meter is only providing +/- 10%, then I wouldn't worry too much about errors introduced by using a +/- 5% 250-ohm resistor.